# Build Output Files

Tags: stenciljs

I am in the process of evaluating a couple of web component libraries/helpers/frameworks and based on its simplicity as well as its robustness I am inclined to select stenciljs but...

I am having a second thoughts since I don't know how to solve that the project created with `npm init stencil` and selecting `component` as part of the presented options containing **two components** generates about **17 files**.

If those files are needed, I really don't care how many are generated.

However I noticed that by creating another project for another set of components, the setup generate files with same name and content as in the other project, and also files with different names but content about 90% similar.

Both set of components (from each project) will be used from the same page and I am wonder if there is a way to deploy both projects output to the same location avoiding files and code duplication.

Any idea in how to solve the deployment issue without me having the set of components in the same project?

Comment: The amount of generated files doesn't represent the amount of files that are actually loaded when you use the components. I assume the majority of the "similar content" files are the polyfills which are only conditionally loaded if the browser needs them (Edge 18-, IE11, and some old Firefox versions), so in most cases this is probably not a problem. I would just give it a go and see how much data is actually used when using both libraries on the same page.

Comment: An approach to reducing the amount of files/similar code would be to create a third stencil project, then import both your libraries there, so they'll both be included when building a `dist`-type output target. Not sure it's worth the effort though.

Comment: Or, if you're certain that both sets of components will always be used together, you might be able to [disable the polyfills](https://stenciljs.com/docs/config-extras) for one of them. Never tried that though.

Comment: I removed support for legacy browsers and about 6 files were removed. I am going to continue investigating... thanks a lot for all your answers and suggestions